# Hosting asp.net mvc5 on win server 2008 iis

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-server-2008-r2

I've created a asp.net mvc 5 page, like so
[image]

Im working on a Windows Server 2008 R2.

I want to host my website and i've tried the method explained on this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ymjT8C-tHc

After i publish my website with visual studio , if i try to open it, i get this

[image]

Is something missing on that tutorial?
The "end game" objective is to get the website accessible from outside

http://11.11.11.11/KMPG

for example.

Comment: Does /KMPG exists in your webapp as route. Please first try localhost to see if you see the default route works. In your application you would have something like RouteConfig.cs please check the routes.MapRoute default in that.

Comment: KPMG was the name i gave the application in IIS (1:30 in video tutorial), when i run my project in visual studio it shows this http://localhost:2247/Home/Index
i tried doing /KPMG/Home/index and other variants but still no luck